# Returning a pointer from member function c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

If I want to return a pointer from a member-function I first thought the syntax should look like the following:

```
 char SecondClass:: *getName() {
   return this->name;
 }
```

But I got an error-message in Eclipse that it couldn't solve the field "name". Somehow it becomes hidden in this case.

The correct solution is this

```
 char *SecondClass:: getName() {
   return this->name;
 }
```

That is putting an * before the classname instead of the function-name.

So my question is: why is the first function not working and what is the difference between these implementations of returning pointers from member-functions?

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with pointers. The method is called `SecondClass::getName()` and it returns a char*. So you can write

```
char* SecondClass::getName()
```

or

```
char *SecondClass::getName()
```

but you can't put the * between the class name and the method name.

Answer (score 1):

`char SecondClass:: *getName()` is a very different function from `char *SecondClass:: getName()`.

The first one not a member function of `SecondClass` or any other class, thus you cannot refer to `this` inside it. It happens to return a special kind of pointer called *pointer-to-member*. Its type is spelled `char SecondClass:: *` and it is a pointer to a member of type `char` in class `SecondClass`. You probably don't want to know any of this just yet.

The ssyntax you want is *return-type function-name parameter-list*. You want to define a function named `SecondClass::getName` that returns a `char *` and takes no parameters, thus `char *SecondClass::getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, the signature of a member function is 
    [returnType] [ClassName]::functionName{}

the star is part of the return type, which is char*, or pointer to a char. Your first way of declaring a function is just not valid c++.